# Navigate from viewpager2 to another fragment (Androidx navigation)

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, androidx, android-viewpager2

I have Orders fragment, into that I have viewpager2 for showing current and old orders.
Now I want to navigate from viewpager2 fragments(current and old) to orderDetail fragment.

```
findNavController().navigate(OrdersFragmentDirections.actionOrdersFragmentToOrdersDetailsFragment(it.orderId))
```

That work successfully, but when I want nav back like this

```
findNavController().popBackStack()
```

this crash happened

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.ensureExecReady(FragmentManager.java:1931)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1967)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNow(BackStackRecord.java:305)
    at androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter$FragmentMaxLifecycleEnforcer.updateFragmentMaxLifecycle(FragmentStateAdapter.java:726)
    at androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter$FragmentMaxLifecycleEnforcer$3.onStateChanged(FragmentStateAdapter.java:657)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:360)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.forwardPass(LifecycleRegistry.java:271)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.sync(LifecycleRegistry.java:313)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.moveToState(LifecycleRegistry.java:151)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:134)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:3026)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.start(FragmentStateManager.java:589)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:300)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2180)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2106)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:524)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

I try to use viewpager2 fragments Directions But that didn't work either